# Getting uncasted error for no reason

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am fairly new to visual basic, so it may be obvious, but I see no reason for this to throw and uncasted exception error. Here is the problem code:

```
    Public Sub textBoxFilePath_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles textboxFilePath.TextChanged
    If textboxFilePath.Text.Trim.Length > 0 Then
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(textboxFilePath.Text) Then
            Dim checkType As String
            checkType = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(textboxFilePath.Text)
            If checkType = ".xlsx" Or ".xls" Or ".xlsm" Then
                requiredPath = True
            Else
                requiredPath = False
            End If
        End If
        End If
```

The error I am getting is

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: Conversion from string ".xls" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
If checkType = ".xlsx" Or checkType = ".xls" Or checkType = ".xlsm" Then
    requiredPath = True
Else
    requiredPath = False
End If
```

Your code was trying to evaluate ".xls" (which is a string), which does not convert nicely to a boolean true/false.

You could also do this to apply "short circuiting", so only the first one true is evaluated:

```
If checkType = ".xlsx" OrElse checkType = ".xls" OrElse checkType = ".xlsm" Then
    requiredPath = True
Else
    requiredPath = False
End If
```

Comment: Oh wow, I should have thought have that. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello Mmm, my question was answered too fast for me to mark as the correct answer. I have to wait 4 more minutes!

Comment: Or you could do this: `requiredPath = {".xls", ".xlsx", ".xlsm"}.Contains(checkType)`